# How to debug cups-pdf

Tags: debian, pdf, cups

The documentation for Cups and Cups-PDF explain that one should set `loglevel` to `debug` and all will be explained; but sadly, /var/log/cups/error_log only says:

```
D [14/Jul/2023:12:59:27 -0400] [Job 7] PID 963956 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf) crashed on signal 11.
W [14/Jul/2023:12:59:27 -0400] [Job 7] Backend returned status -139 (crashed)
```

- Debian bookworm (12)
- cups 2.4.2-3
- printer-driver-cups-pdf 3.0.1-14